# How do I clear fields using KnockoutJs and typescript?

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, reset

I know these things are very easy in jQuery, but I don't know how to do with KO and TS. Here's my code :

Html

```
    <div class="form_container">
        <div class="label-n-input_container">
            <div class="input_container">
                <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: $root.term" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clear-button_container">
            <button class="" data-bind="click: $root.clearSearch">Clear search</label>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things are in fact way easier in knockout than with jquery, since view's properties can be bound to observables.

That means each time something changes behind the scene (in the viewModel objects), the view can update accordingly automatically.

In your particular case you need to create a viewModel object, which has a term property ([observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html)), and a clearSearch function, which resets this observable :

```js
var vm = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.term = ko.observable("default");
  self.clearSearch = function() {
    self.term("");
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="form_container">
        <div class="label-n-input_container">
            <div class="input_container">
                <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: $root.term" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clear-button_container">
            <button class="" data-bind="click: $root.clearSearch">Clear search</label>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This will work in both javascript and typescript (since the latter includes the former).

However, if you want compile time type checks, automatic management of "this", and other typescript's goodness, you can write the following piece of code :

```
    // import actual knockout declarations from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/knockout/index.d.ts
interface KnockoutObservable<T> {
    (): T;
    (value: T | null): void;
}

interface Knockout {
    applyBindings(vm: any): void;
    observable<T>(value: T): KnockoutObservable<T>;
}

declare var ko: Knockout;

class vm  {
    public term: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    constructor() {
        this.term = ko.observable("default");
    }

    public clearSearch() {
      this.term("");
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```